# Binding to a brush cause memory leack?

Tags: wpf, binding, brush

Let's say I have following classes in my app.

### MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public SolidColorBrush Brush { get; set; } 

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.AliceBlue);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 window = new Window1();
        window.DataContext = this;
        window.ShowDialog();
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, (Action)delegate
                                                                           {
                                                                               GC.Collect();
                                                                               GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                                                                               GC.Collect();
                                                                           });
    }
```

### MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Do It</Button>
</Window>
```

### Window1.xaml.cs

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    ~Window1()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Window1 Finalized");
    }
}
```

### Window1.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300"
        Background="{Binding Brush}">
    <Grid>
        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When I launch app, click `Do It` button and close opened window - `Debug.WriteLine("Window1 Finalized");` is not execute. This means that Window1 object is still in memory and not GCed. But if I remove brush binding from `Window1.xaml` - "Window1 Finalized" string appears in output. This means that Window1 object is GCed.

How does binding keep object in memory? Is it bug or is it a way binding is implemented?

### Edit 1

If I bind Foreground property instead of Background property, Window1 is finalized. So it seems it is not a Dependency system effect, but an effect of the Background property implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The window1 is not finalized because there are still references to it from the Binding syntax in its BackGround property.

Although the Binding is OneWay, the fact that there is a binding to MainWindow's Property, means there is a reference to Window1 from Mainwindow (because of the way the dependency system works)  - therefore the Window1 isn't a candidate for Garbage Collection (and therefore wont be finalized)

Comment: But if I bind Title property to string instead of bind Background property to SolidColorBrush - Window1 is finalized. What the difference?

Comment: I think its because string is immutable and behaves like a valuetype, which is passed by reference. SolidColorBrush is an object, so there is a GC reference

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Calling the freeze method on the brush after creation resolved it.